# Addthis Facebook Share

Tags: facebook, addthis

having problems with facebook share with the AddThis bar which is driving me crazy.

I've set the og url etc as suggested by the support team but it takes FOREVER to connect to facebook - all I receive is a message saying 'connecting to facebook'....I've put the URL into the facebook debug and all fine.

Anyone got any ideas? I've contacted AddThis support team days ago and no response :-/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either a problem on Facebook's end or a problem on your end when connecting to Facebook. Have you tried using the plain Facebook Like button from Facebook to see if that's the problem and not AddThis? You can get that button here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Also, if the Facebook URL debugger says your site is working it's probably set up correctly, just running slow.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I currently have a plain facebook button that doesn't go through AddThis and that works instantly... This'll teach me for trying to get sharing stats!